# String iteration programming

Tags: go, string-iteration

I'd like to write a function able to generate an array of string with iteration in Go programming language.

Enter a unique name for the signal path in the field titled Description. Since the field features an iterator, multiple, consecutively counted signal paths can be set-up by using curly brackets, for example "**Source {1-16:2} {Left, Right} >**"

The result is an array of string:

```
Source 01 Left >
Source 01 Right >
Source 02 Left >
Source 02 Right >
...
Source 16 Left >
Source 16 Right >
```

I could have an undefined curly brackets iterator in the string.

- The first curly brackets {1-16:2} indicate  1-16 : increment value
  from 1 to 16 :2 is the padding that means two digits
- The second curly brackets [Left, Right} indicate a defined list of
  value.

Comment: This is not a question, this is a request/work description.

Comment: Edit the question and add the code you're using, how it's not working, and how it should be working. That will help you get some answers.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code. What problems are you encountering?

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the code yet.

Today I have an UI interface where I have some optional fields to fill.

- signal path : "Source" as the unique identifier (as string) (Mandatory)
- counter : "16" increment value from 1 till 16 (as integer) (optional)

  Source 1
  Source 2
  Source 3
  ...
  Source 16

If I would like to create a signal path like this:

```
Source 01 Left >
Source 01 Right >
```

I need to do it manually. If I have 1000 signal path to create it will take hours with errors and if the counter > 0 then increment value will be added at the end of the signal path and no padding.

Now I am looking some help if any libraries could analyze my string iteration "**Source {1-16:2} {Left, Right}**" and generate the string as expected.

Best regards,
Youssef